# How to change content with toggle button with html css and js

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, wordpress

I am building a website and am having a little issue with toggle switches.

I've built my toggle button but I want to add a function to swap contents.

I want to add 2 contents and they are really easy but I could not make it. When toggled right i want to display a text in div which says "Hey" and when toggled left i want to display a text again which says "Bye". What should i add?

How can I make this happen?

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #E21C90;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  background-color: #E21C90;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require hook an event handler to the checkbox `input` and then toggle the `display` setting of the parent elements of the sliders based on the state of that checkbox. Note that in this example I used `div` elements as the parents, but any block-level element would work.

```js
let mainContent = document.querySelector('#main_content');
let secondaryContent = document.querySelector('#secondary_content');

document.querySelector('.switch input').addEventListener('change', e => { 
  mainContent.style.display = e.target.checked ? 'block' : 'none';
  secondaryContent.style.display = e.target.checked ? 'none' : 'block';
});
```

```css
.switch {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 60px;
  height: 34px;
}

.switch input {
  opacity: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

.slider {
  position: absolute;
  cursor: pointer;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  background-color: #ccc;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

.slider:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  left: 4px;
  bottom: 4px;
  background-color: white;
  -webkit-transition: .4s;
  transition: .4s;
}

input:checked+.slider {
  background-color: #E21C90;
}

input:focus+.slider {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px #2196F3;
  background-color: #E21C90;
}

input:checked+.slider:before {
  -webkit-transform: translateX(26px);
  -ms-transform: translateX(26px);
  transform: translateX(26px);
}


/* Rounded sliders */

.slider.round {
  border-radius: 34px;
}

.slider.round:before {
  border-radius: 50%;
}

#secondary_content {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<label class="switch">
  <input type="checkbox" checked>
  <span class="slider round"></span>
</label>

<div id="main_content">Slider 1</div>
<div id="secondary_content">Slider 2</div>
```

Comment: Rory it worked perfectly, thank you. To people who is gonna use this snipper for create their own, if you are using wordpress theme builders like elemantor or wpbakery just use first part as a script, with tags in html editor or rawjs modules. Second one needs to be in html and head tags. And html should finish with 3rd part.